# About google api i want to display more than 100 points on google API road map

Tags: javascript, google-api

i want to display more than 100 points on google API road map..
i referred this link to display route https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/inspector but this link not allowing me more thank 100 snapped points to display route

Answer (score 3):

Per the API's overview [overview page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/intro) stating:

> **Snap to roads**: This service takes up to 100 GPS points
> collected along a route, and returns a similar set of data with the
> points snapped to the most likely roads the vehicle was traveling
> along.

However, there are ways to achieve the behavior you are looking for found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/advanced). Wherein it states that for processing long paths, as the snap to road feature is limited 100-point-paths-per-request, the remedy is to produce multiple requests and then:

> treat the individual requests as one long path, you should include
> some overlap, such that the final points from the previous request are
> included as the first points of the subsequent request. The number of
> points to include depends on the accuracy of your data

Unfortunately, the links provided are for Googles Java client. However, for your application you can find their node.js examples. (link at top of page or on their github page)

Hope this helps!